# Angular ui.boostrap - passing a slide number into the carousel

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a slide number into the ui.bootstrap carousel.  In the Plunker below, I have two buttons - one which simply opens a modal which contains a slide carousel.  The other does the same (Open to slide 3), but passes the slide number to display in the modal carousel.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the slide number from the open function in the carousel to display the selected slide number when "Open to slide 3" is clicked.

How do I make that happen?

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="ItemsCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(2)">Open to slide 3!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jV3fc2u0ud45BRRNymwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your ModalInstanceCtrl function add this to your code:

```
    var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, modalName, slideTo) {

     $scope.items = items;
     $scope.modalName = modalName;
     $scope.slideTo = slideTo;

     // this is what tell the carousel wich item should be active.
     if(slideTo){
       items[slideTo].active=true;
     }
...
```